# Windows 10 Install using WinPE on USB - Boot Loop After Applying Image

Tags: windows-10, bcdedit, unattended, winpe

I am applying a Windows 10 wim image via WinPE which I captured using dism.

After the image has finished applying to the disk, if I forget to remove the USB flash drive from the USB port the device reboots back into WinPE on the USB flash drive, this starts the whole process again (diskpart, format, apply-image etc).

If I remove the USB flash drive before restarting, the system boots into the Windows 10 install and completes the Sysprep steps as expected.

I have checked the UEFI settings with BCDEdit but can't identify what's causing the system to boot the USB device first.

How can I prevent the system from booting back into the USB flash drive? Ideally I'm looking for a command line I can add to my custom WinPE shell before restarting.

Comment: I am not clear on what you want. Windows 10 on USB is pretty much dead. If you want Windows 10 on a computer, use the Windows 10 ISO, make it bootable (Rufus) and install it normally.

Comment: The boot-order is defined inside the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from USB is typically a UEFI/BIOS firmware option, not a Windows boot manager option. I have never seen any command line programs capable of editing firmware boot orders.

You should look for whatever key your motherboard needs you to press to enter firmware configuration and then change the boot order. Many motherboards have a separate key to select a boot device as the system boots up.

The normal process would be to go into the firmware options set the "usual" boot device, the hard drive, and then use the boot device key to choose an alternative boot device such as the USB stick.

Some UEFI "fast boot" modes make it difficult to boot into the firmware settings because the boot keys are disabled, so once Windows is installed you may need to [access the firmware settings in another way](https://aavtech.site/2018/06/access-uefi-firmware-settings-using-windows-10/).

Comment: Here's the interesting thing. I have previously been using a regular Windows 10 Unattended install using an AutoUnattend.xml file to install Windows 10 via USB. Using that process I could insert the USB into the device and walk away, come back an hour later and Windows was built. Now I've converted to applying a captured WIM image, I can't as it reboots back into WinPE on the USB stick. There must be something in the standard Windows installation that prevents the system booting back off the USB drive after applying the image

Comment: On a machine with a blank hard drive the boot order set up correctly with HDD first and USB last will mean that the USB is the only valid boot device on first setup, otherwise you can hit the "boot manager" BIOS key when booting to select the USB, then once the hard disk is made bootable by the installer there is a valid boot device that appears before the USB disk when the system is booting. What you've said just suggests that your WIM image is not making a valid boot disk. Are you configuring a valid UEFI boot partition while setting up Windows?